# How to create unique id in IF ELSE condition?

Tags: postgresql

Currently, id will start from 1 when IF condition is executed and id will also start from 1 when ELSE condition is executed.

I don't want to create same id. New id should be created.

Is there any way to generate a unique ID for data insert?

```
If p_value=0

Insert into my_table
Select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) as id, now(), total
From my_table2;


Else p_value >0

Insert into my_table
Select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) as id, now(), total
From my_table2;
```

Comment: [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): *GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ]
 This clause creates the column as an identity column. It will have an implicit sequence attached to it and the column in new rows will automatically have values from the sequence assigned to it. Such a column is implicitly NOT NULL.*

Comment: I must be missing something, your if and else blocks are exactly the same?

Comment: Create a sequence. You can get the `nextVal()` to get the next unique entry. Each vlaue can just received once and even if a ID gets free again because of a deletion it will never be re-used (best case). You can also get the last used value but thats just used in rare cases. Thats basic sequence in 2 sentence.

Comment: The question is not defined clearly. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Its preferable to generate [sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) or use [Auto Increment](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-serial/) property for the column. By doing this you will not need to keep record of last ID generated, postgreSQL will itself generate next ID and will insert accordingly.

You can create sequence by:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_id_seq;
```

Next modify your table;

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('my_table_id_seq'),
    -- other columns...
);
```

Now perform insertion:

```
IF p_value = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO my_table (created_at, total)
    SELECT now(), total
    FROM my_table2;
ELSE
    -- Perform your other operation...
END IF;
```